# How to create multiple configurations for Ldap with spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, ldap

i want to make multiple configurations
to integrate between ldap with spring

if i have two different ldap conf, want to integrate with them throw multiple services

Like
service 1 call ldap conf1
service 2 call ldap conf2

and these will be ldap context with spring

Comment: i saw these solution before - but in my case in need two configurations stand alone to use from different services

Use space delimited value for url attribute:

url="ldap://server1/dc=springframework,dc=org ldap://server2/dc=springframework,dc=org"

Comment: Hello AHmed, can you precise your question ? In adding a ? character ! I don't understand your question because 'want' verb don't have any subject ! In title, can you add an interrogative adverb as 'How' or something else ?